# Android Listview in fragment, items show empty content

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I find this a little strange. I have a Fragement activity with a view pager and 4 tabs that are fragments.

In three of the tabs I have listviews. Every time I open my app and scroll to the second tab where i have my first listview, and two items in the list view, the content of the item is empty. Untill I scroll to the 4th tab and back to the second, so a refresh of that fragment has been made is my guess.

Here is the second fragment when opened the first time:
http://postimg.org/image/84413xncd/

& Here is the same fragment opened again by scrolling to contacts and back:
http://postimg.org/image/afhhle3bn/

This is how I set the list in the fragment, helper.list is a List.

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (helper.news != null) {
        NewsArrayAdapter newsAdapter = new NewsArrayAdapter(getActivity(), 0, helper.news);
        list.setAdapter(newsAdapter);
    }
}
```

And this is my custom adapter:

```
public class NewsArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<JSONObject> {
    private Context context;
    private List<JSONObject> items;
    MainHelper helper = null;

    public NewsArrayAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List<JSONObject> items) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, items);
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
        helper = MainHelper.getHelper();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int p, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row_news, parent, false);

        TextView name = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        name.setText(items.get(p).optString("name"));
        name.setTypeface(Font.rLight(context));

        TextView date = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        date.setText(Methods.getMethods().getDate(context, items.get(p).optLong("dateAdded"), R.string.date_format_date_month));
        date.setTypeface(Font.rLight(context));

        ProgressBar spinner = (ProgressBar) rowView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);

        if (items.get(p).optString("photoURL") == null || items.get(p).optString("photoURL").equals("")) {
            image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else Methods.getMethods().loadImageView(context, items.get(p).optString("photoURL"), image, spinner);

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

The images are loaded from a url in an asynctask, so in other words is a small delay to them and thats why I think they show, but why not the text?

Comment: Did you check if `helper.news != null`?

Comment: @just_user im facing some sort of similar issue, how did you solved your problem? I'm using ListView with in nested fragment when i add an item to the list images gets updated but textview remains empty. Please share your solution with me. Thank you

Comment: @NaumanZubair I had a mistake in my code where the list I used missed the content. So the adapter itself had no problem. Check that you have content!

Comment: @just_user here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24119696/listview-in-nested-fragment-showing-empty-list-item-only-textviews-not-images[1] i posted my question can you please point me what i'm doing wrong

Answer (score -1):

use lazy loading for download and display you images from server in listView. see [this](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/09/23/simplest-lazy-loading-listview-android-data-populated-mysql-database-php/)

Comment: This isn't what I asked for. If you checked the links you would have seen that the images load just fine.